# How to setVisible(true or false) multiple components with single statement

Tags: java, swing

I am making Store inventory App using netbeans JFrame. In there I have used almost 50+jLabels. what I want to do is when some one click the button, all components within the button action should be setVisible true or False. I have to write multiple lines to do that, which makes my code looks complex.

I want that code in very short lines. Is there any way to do so?
I have multiple MouseClicked events.
Here is the sample code:

```
private void jLabel15MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

    jScrollPane1.setVisible(true);
    jLabel42.setVisible(false);
    jLabel43.setVisible(false);
    jLabel44.setVisible(false);      
    jLabel48.setVisible(false);
    jLabel40.setVisible(false);
    jLabel20.setVisible(false);
    jLabel19.setVisible(false);
    jLabel18.setVisible(false);
    jLabel17.setVisible(false);
    jLabel22.setVisible(false);
    jLabel21.setVisible(true);
    jLabel37.setVisible(false);
    jLabel38.setVisible(false);
    jLabel39.setVisible(false);

}
```

Comment: create a array of labels then use a loop or you can use `getComponents()` methods

Comment: Put them into a single container and make the container visible/invisible

Comment: no, I can't because there are some labels true and some are false on every MouseClicke event

Comment: So there's no logical group to the labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way you can put all lables in array then you can loop throw it and change visibility

create a array of jlabels

```
JLabel[] labels=new JLabel[]{jLabel1,jLabel2};
```

then loop and change visibility

```
private void jLabel15MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {  

    for (JLabel label : labels) {
           label.setVisible(false); // use your logic to set visibility 
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks awsome work I was looking axactly for it. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

Put them into a single container and make the container visible/invisible

Also, you might consider using a [`CardLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 1):

try this 
  Use SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Component) to find the parent window of the current component. You can then call setVisible on it.